# How to run Batch Job EST 1:00 AM everyday?

Tags: apex

In `salesforce` is there any way to run the **Batch Job** `midnight` at `EST` time everyday ?
I know following cron runs everyday at 1:00 AM. But not sure on which timezone will it run ?

Cron format ==>

```
0 0 1 1/1 * ? *
```

I dont see a way to configure the timezone actually. Any way ?

```
System.schedule('TSAMPLE Job1', '0 0 1 1/1 * ? *', new My_Scheduler());
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned here:
[Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) the The System.Schedule method uses the user's timezone for the basis of all schedules.

Hope this helps.